# Have a Syntax issue with quotes in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to point the `src` to an images folder, but struggling to get the syntax correct.

`get_stylesheet_directory()` is a wordpress specific php function, which basically says point to the theme folder.

I've posted this not in the wordpress specific area of this site, as it is purely a syntax problem I'm having.

```
if ($twitter) {
   echo "<a href='$twitter' target='_blank'><img src= " get_stylesheet_directory(). '/images'" height='38' width='37' alt='Twitter'>";  
}
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Please can someone tell me why this has been marked down? it seems to comply with the guidelines. Thank-you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this syntax

```
echo  '<a href="'.$twitter.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory().'/images" height="38" width="37" alt="Twitter">';
```

Comment: Thank-you, the links now work, but no images are being shown still.

Comment: you are giving `<theme-folder>/images` as source for the image. May be you forgot the add `/imagename.png` or something like this

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator in PHP joins strings together.

You need a `.` betweeen `...src= "` and `get_stylesheet_directory()`, and another `.` between `'/images'` and the following `" height='38'..."` to properly join all the strings together.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a `</a>` missing as well as missing concatenation, try this:

```
if ($twitter) 
{
   echo "<a href='$twitter' target='_blank'><img src='".get_stylesheet_directory()."/images' height='38' width='37' alt='Twitter'></a>";  
}
```

Also note that the image source is pointing to the **folder** `/images`, not an image file.